# What does single stepping an instruction means in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, kernel, debugging

[The kprobes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kprobes.txt) says:

> ```
> #include <linux/kprobes.h>
> int register_kprobe(struct kprobe *kp);
> ```
>
> Sets a breakpoint at the address `kp->addr`.  When the breakpoint is
>   hit, Kprobes calls `kp->pre_handler`.  After the probed instruction
>   is single-stepped, Kprobe calls `kp->post_handler`.

In the above context, what does single-stepped means?

Answer (score 0):

In this context in mean executed, possibly with some monitoring.

It is not exactly correct to say single step a single instruction. It is like in walking would you say single step one step. It is just redundant. We may say walk a 100 miles one step at a time. Or make one step (to single step).

Single stepping is what you do to a set of instructions (a program). You run one instruction at a time, and can then look at the state of the machine between steps/instructions.

In this context it probably means that it does what even it does when single stepping, but for just that one instruction.

Comment: “It is not correct to say single step a single instruction.” I don’t understand why not — when you single-step, you single-step a single instruction. If you want to step through a series of instructions you either set a breakpoint (so you’re no longer single-stepping) or you handle every individual step. Continuing to single-step is a decision you make every time; the next single-step has to be set up again.